# Reference different classes with one variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, variables, optimization

There are some classes in my project, each class has a method "`public void build(){...}`", but each method is different. I need something like:

```
    ...
    switch (choose){
    case 1:
    class = new Class1();
    break;

    case 2:
    class = new Class2();
    break;

    ...

    case 20:
    class = new Class20();
    break;
    }
    ...

    class.build();

    ...
```

each class has a very long code, so i rather to separate each class, i'll implement some classes in other application too.

So, there is a way to reference classes in a unique variable?

Answer (score 1):

Make all of those classes implement an interface called `Buildable` that lists the `build()` method.

Then you can have a variable

```
Buildable thingImGoingToBuild;
```

and set it to any object of any of those classes.  Once you've done that, you'll be able to write

```
thingImGoingToBuild.build();
```

Comment: Thanks. i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array & then call build method on each array item

```
...
ClassName[] className = new ClassName[Count]
switch(choose){
case N:
className[N] = new ClassNameNewN();
break;
case K:
className[K] = new ClassNameNewK();
break;
}

//for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)//if you want to call all 
      ClassName[i].build();

...
```